# Change IntelliSense Box location in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, intellisense

Is it possible to change the location of IntelliSense Box in Visual Studio?

[image]

Like make this appear above my current "typing position" or whereever?

Comment: Side note - It will appear above typing position when you are typing at the bottom of the screen. But usually you should look on the code which you just typed to see the context of what you are doing. Why you want to show  intellisense box on lines you just typed?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that. Its so convenient were it's supposed to be.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy to see code below, which is usually hidden by it. Tired of slamming in 5-10 times Enter just to see it while typing.

Comment: @hYde you are typing bottom-up?